# Test whether an object implements a generic interface for any generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, interface

I want to test an object to see if it implements `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` but I don't care what `TKey` and `TValue` are.

I can test if is a concrete instance of the framework `Dictionary<,>` like this:

```
bool isDict = type.IsGenericType && 
    (typeof(Dictionary<,>).IsAssignableFrom(type.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
```

but I can't think of a way to test for something that implements `IDictionary<,>`. This technique doesn't work for the interface; `IsAssignableFrom` return false if I test against the generic base type `IDictionary<,>`, which seems odd since it works for the concrete type.

Normally you would use `is` to test if something implements an interface, but of course this only works if I want to test for a specific generic interface. Or I would just test for a common ancestral interface, but unlike other generic data structures such as `IList<>` and `ICollection<>`, there is no unique non-generic interface from which the generic `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` inherits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about something like

```
return type.GetInterfaces()
           .Where(t => t.IsGenericType)
           .Select(t => t.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
           .Any(t => t.Equals(typeof(IDictionary<,>)));
```

which I'm sure that you can easily generalize for any generic type definition.

Comment: Like. How did I overlook GetInterfaces?