# c# testing if an object implements ISurface<T> of any Type using .GetType().GetInterface(typeof(ISurface<>).FullName)

Tags: c#, linq, generics, interface

I have a plugin architecture where I need to detect all plugins that implement interface `ISurface<T>` of any Type (i.e. test for `ISurface<>`). I see there are several suggestions here using LINQ (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10900084/478267)), and I am wondering if there are reasons to favor that over this:

```
.GetType().GetInterface("ISurface`1")
```

***Edit**: Regarding hardcoding the interface name, I assume those concerns would be mitigated if the name was extracted from the actual interface directly, as Tim also mentioned below:*

```
.GetType().GetInterface(typeof(ISurface<>).FullName)
```

*With* `.FullName` *there should be no problem with namespace ambiguity either. Hardcoding aside, I am primarily interested in the approach itself, as it seems shorter and cleaner than going through a series of type property checking / LINQ syntax. Then again, I don't know what's going on under the hood.*

Comment: what if you change name of your interface, or make second one called ISurface? Hardcoded class/interface names are evil!

Comment: @wudzik - A second one would be either `ISurface` or `ISurface\`2`, depending on the number of type arguments it had.  But yes, hardcoding is problematic.

Comment: @Bobson yeah, would, but we can't be sure :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you would extract all the supported interfaces of type `ISurface<anything>`:

```
void Main()
{
    var supportedInterfaces =
        from intf in typeof(Test).GetInterfaces()
        where intf.IsGenericType
        let genericIntf = intf.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
        where genericIntf == typeof(ISurface<>)
        select intf;

    supportedInterfaces.Dump();
}

public class Test : ISurface<int>
{
}

public interface ISurface<T>
{
}
```

You can test this in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) (the `.Dump()` extension method is a LINQPad extension).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this approach (this is pretty much the same solution I linked to in my question). I was primarily interested in how going through `GetInterface` stacks up, given that it is arguably shorter and "cleaner".

Answer (score 0):

If you check just by the 'simple' name of the interface (instead of the fully specified class name, incl namespaces), then you will have problems if you have another interface with the same name in another namespace.

If you call the `GetInterface` method with the fully specified class name, it should work ok.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayfa0fcd.aspx) specifically mentions that for generic types you should specify the mangled name, so I would expect it to work fine.

Of course, if it is the best method, can be debated. If you change the interface name, you will have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's an *implementation detail* that could be subject to change.  Plus you lose run-time type safely.  I would rather stick with *public* methods - either by using Linq as you found or using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons that come to mind why you might not want to do this:

1. If you refactor your code so that `` "ISurface`1" `` is no longer valid (e.g. add or remove type parameters or rename the interface), the compiler won't catch it. This can be solved by replacing it with `typeof(ISurface<>).Name`.
2. If there's an `ISurface<>` in another namespace, it is ambiguous (or, at least, at first glance it appears so).

I'd probably go with [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900021/test-whether-an-object-implements-a-generic-interface-for-any-generic-type) you linked, maybe wrapped in an extension method so that I could call it more simply, e.g.

```
public static Type GetInterface(this Type type, Type targetType)
{
    return type.GetInterfaces().SingleOrDefault(t => t.IsGenericType
                          && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == targetType);
}
public class Surface : ISurface<int> { /* ... */ }

typeof(Surface).GetInterface(typeof(ISurface<>)); //returns typeof(ISurface<int>)
typeof(NotASurface).GetInterface(typeof(ISurface<>)); //returns null
```

Comment: Wouldn't single or default be a problem if the type implemented two copies of the generic interface eg `ISurface<string>` and `ISurface<bool>`

Comment: @BobVale yes, it would. If you expect such things to occur, then you need to handle it somehow (and probably not just with `FirstOrDefault`!).

Answer (score 0):

If you have any control over the interface in question, I would suggest that `ISurface<T>` should inherit from a non-generic `ISurface`.  That type could in turn include a member which could indicate in various means the types for which `ISurface<T>` would be available (e.g. if one defined an interface `ITypeRegistrar { Register<TType>(info about type);}`, the non-generic `ISurface` could include a `RegisterSupportedTypes(ITypeRegistrar registrar)` method.  Depending upon what exact information was associated with each type, a typical implementation might look like:

```
void RegisterSupportedTypes(ITypeRegistrar registrar)
{
   registrar.Register<Circle>(circleFactory);
   registrar.Register<Square>(squareFactory);
   registrar.Register<Rhombus>(rhombusFactory);
}
```

The client code would be receiving each item as its actual generic type, so using this approach would allow the program to operate without typecasts or Reflection.  Because .NET has no concept of open generic delegates, the client code would have to manually implement the `ITypeRegistrar` interface (instead of using something like lambda syntax as a shortcut for creating a delegate) but the implemented method that could do something like store a reference to the supplied factory into a field of a static generic class without using Reflection, which is something a delegate wouldn't be able to do.

Comment: Yes, I know. Even simpler, the non-generic ISurface could expose a readonly property of type Type (e.g. `Type SurfaceType { get; }` that represents the type of the inner <T> from the derived class and which can be used for further discrimination and checking. That wasn't the question, though.

Comment: @d7samurai: I wasn't clear whether you want to use Reflection to construct a generic type because you like using reflection, or whether you weren't aware of any way to implement a pattern that wouldn't require it.  In some situations, the code will want to invoke a factory using a `Type` parameter, but in other cases it will want to use a generic type parameter.  If the normal client paradigm will be to use generic type parameters, I prefer to keep things in that mold, though there are cases where each approach will have its own advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @d7samurai: Among other things, if many of the types will be structures, using generic type parameters will cause separate machine-code routines to be built for each type, but the code for each type will have hard-coded jumps to interface implementations; using `Type` parameters will often result in less code generation but more virtual dispatch.