# Workaround when dealing with generic interfaces

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, interface

I have the following interface:

```
public interface ITranslatable<T> : IPersistableEntity where T : Translation {
    ICollection<T> Translations { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, the generic type parameter can only be a `Translation` type or a child.

Somewhere else in my application, I have the following piece of code:

```
foreach(E entity in entities) {
    if(entity is ITranslatable<?>)
      //Cast the entity and access the ICollection<?> property
}
```

As you can see by the **?** I don't know what to pass in as the type parameter. I don't want to pass that specific type by generics to that class, as I did with `E`, because I'm only using it there and I want it to be transparent.

`entity is ITranslatable<Translation>` won't work, because `ITranslatable<Translation>` is different from `ITranslatable<TranslationImpl>`, even though `TranslationImpl` ***extends*** from `Translation`.

Another thing that occured to me was doing the following:

```
public interface ITranslatable : IPersistableEntity {
    ICollection<Translation> Translations { get; set; }
}

public interface ITranslatable<T> : ITranslatable where T : Translation {
    ICollection<T> Translations { get; set; }
}
```

But again, when implementing this interface, I end up with two different properties, which is redundant and ugly.

Just for the record, I **really** need the property in the child class to be of `Collection<TranslationImpl>` and not `Collection<Translation>`, because **EntityFramework** does not support abstract classes mapping.

**PS**: I don't really need to use `ICollection<TranslationImpl>` for the application code snippet above, an access to `ICollection<Translation>` will suffice.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using the additional interface approach, is implementing the `ICollection<Translation> Translations` property [explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) not an option for you? Objects that implement `ITranslatable<T>` will only have the `ICollection<T> Translations` property (well, they actually do, but it's hidden), while objects that implement `ITranslatable` only have `ICollection<Translation> Translations`.

Comment: @hantoun Cannot have objects implementing `ICollection<Translation>` because `Translation` is an abstract class, and EF cries about it. I do want, however, to be able to cast the implementention to an interface, where I can fetch the properties as `ICollection<Translation>`, even if at the implementation they are `ICollection<T>`

Comment: duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900021/test-whether-an-object-implements-a-generic-interface-for-any-generic-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't determine if a type implements an open geenric interface using the `is` operator, but you can do it using reflection'

```
if(entity.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(x =>
  x.IsGenericType &&
  x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ITranslatable<>)))
```

Comment: Interesting approach! Will try it and let you know. (By the way, how would I **cast** my entity to the interface without knowing the type parameter? That's not possible, right? I do know the type parameters's **base class** though)