# Mysteriously inconsistent behaviour of Type.IsAssignableTo() when calling on a concrete type with a parameter that is an open generic interface type

Tags: c#, generics, types, interface

My generic method fails because `bool isOrderedField = typeof(T).IsAssignableTo(typeof(INumber<>));` evaluates (according to my intent, erroneously) to `false` for a generic extension method of signature `public static T[][] MovingStatistics<T>(this IReadOnlyList<T> source, int radius, T[][] target, bool calculateStandardDeviation = false, bool calculateExtrema = false, int startIndex = 0, int length = -1) where T : INumberBase<T>` when the latter is called on a `double` array. I have tried to investigate and come up with the following minimum example (I was suspicious of the fact that the culprit is an extension method, that is why I tested it both ways):

```
using System.Numerics;

namespace InferredGenericMethodTypeBehaviour
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] array = new double[] { 11.0 };
            Console.WriteLine($"The method [{nameof(Program.IsItAListOfNumbers)}] says the statement that [{nameof(array)}] comprises numbers is {IsItAListOfNumbers(array)}.");
            Console.WriteLine($"The method [{nameof(Extensions.AmIAListOfNumbers)}] says the statement that [{nameof(array)}] comprises numbers is {array.AmIAListOfNumbers()}.");
        }

        static bool IsItAListOfNumbers<T>(IReadOnlyList<T> list) where T : INumberBase<T> => typeof(T).IsAssignableTo(typeof(INumber<>));
       
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static bool AmIAListOfNumbers<T>(this IReadOnlyList<T> array) where T : INumberBase<T> => typeof(T).IsAssignableTo(typeof(INumber<>));
    }
}
```

This is NOT an MWE as it cannot reproduce the behaviour that got me investigating in the first place. The output will be

> The method [IsItAListOfNumbers] says the statement that [array] comprises numbers is True.
>
> The method [AmIAListOfNumbers] says the statement that [array] comprises numbers is True.

In my desperation, I inserted the following line into the offending code:

```
 bool amIEvil = new double[] { 11.0 }.ConsistsOfNumbers();
```

where the generic extension method `ConsistsOfNumbers()` is identical to the minimum example:

```
public static bool ConsistsOfNumbers<T>(this IReadOnlyList<T> source) where T : INumberBase<T> => typeof(T).IsAssignableTo(typeof(INumber<>));
```

There, in the program I am actually developing, `amIEvil` will evaluate to `false`. Both my actual program and the minimum (non-)working example run in .NET 7.0, on the same machine, under the same settings.

What can cause this difference? I can of course circumvent it in a number of ways, I have found several answers here on stack overflow, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900021/test-whether-an-object-implements-a-generic-interface-for-any-generic-type), and after all since the whole thing is to check whether the type of the number belongs to an ordered field and not a non-ordered one like complex numbers, I can simply replace it with `typeof(T) != typeof(Complex)`, but I cannot wrap my head round this glaring inconsistency.

Your help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

In the comments, I was instructed to publish the full code and the project files, so I shall do so:

Calling code:

```
 private async Task TestCrossSpectrumOnAcqRecording()
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialogue = new OpenFileDialog();
            SettingsWindow settingsWindow;
            double[][] data;
            double[][] spectrumMovingStatistics;
            double fullDuration;
            double samplingInterval;
            double overlap = 0.8;
            double windowWidth = 1.1;
            double startFrequency = 0.1;
            double endFrequency = 10.0;
            double frequencyStep;
            int startFrequencyIndex = 0;
            int frequencyCount = -1;
            int xIndex = 0;
            int yIndex = 1;
            int radius = 33;
            IReadOnlyList<AcqChannelProperties> channels;
            string[] channelNames;
            TetheredSun.Spectral.Window window;
            WindowPropagator windowPropagator;
            WindowedCrossSpectral crossSpectral;
            Recording recording;
            FixedStepDataSequence t;
            FixedStepDataSequence averagedF;
            FixedStepDataSequence totalF;
            ComplexDataSequence xSpectrum;
            ComplexDataSequence ySpectrum;
            RecordingViewModel recordingViewModel;

            dialogue.Title = "Select AcqKnowledge file to open";
            dialogue.Filter = AcqFile.Filter;
            if (dialogue.ShowDialog() is not true) return;

            using (Stream source = new FileStream(dialogue.FileName, FileMode.Open)) {
                using (AcqFile acqFile = new AcqFile(source)) {
                    data = await Task.Run(() => acqFile.ReadAllChannels()).ConfigureAwait(true);
                    samplingInterval = acqFile.SamplingInterval / 1000.0;
                    fullDuration = (acqFile.Count - 1) * samplingInterval;
                    channels = acqFile.ChannelProperties;
                    channelNames = channels.Select(channel => channel.Name).ToArray();
                }
            }

            settingsWindow = new SettingsWindow();
            settingsWindow.Title = "Set parameters for cross-spectral investigations";
            settingsWindow.Settings.Add("Window width [s]", windowWidth);
            settingsWindow.Settings.Add("Window overlap [%]", overlap * 100.0);
            settingsWindow.Settings.Add("Window type", new ListMenu<Type>(windowTypes, windowType => windowType.Name.Decamelise()));
            settingsWindow.Settings.Add("First term of cross spectrum (x)", new ListMenu<string>(channelNames, channelName => channelName, xIndex));
            settingsWindow.Settings.Add("Second term of cross spectrum (y)", new ListMenu<string>(channelNames, channelName => channelName, yIndex));
            if (settingsWindow.ShowDialog() is not true) return;

            windowWidth = settingsWindow.Settings[0].GetValue<double>();
            overlap = settingsWindow.Settings[1].GetValue<double>() / 100.0;
            window = settingsWindow.Settings[2].GetValue<ListMenu<Type>>().Selected.New() as TetheredSun.Spectral.Window;
            xIndex = Array.IndexOf(channelNames, settingsWindow.Settings[3].GetValue<ListMenu<string>>().Selected);
            yIndex = Array.IndexOf(channelNames, settingsWindow.Settings[4].GetValue<ListMenu<string>>().Selected);
            frequencyStep = 1.0 / windowWidth;
            startFrequencyIndex = (int)(startFrequency / frequencyStep);
            frequencyCount = (int)(endFrequency / frequencyStep) - startFrequencyIndex + 1;

            windowPropagator = new WindowPropagator() {
                Width = windowWidth,
                Step = (1.0 - overlap) * windowWidth,
                Window = window
            };
            windowPropagator.SamplingInterval = samplingInterval;

            crossSpectral = new WindowedCrossSpectral() {
                StartFrequencyIndex = startFrequencyIndex,
                FrequencyCount = frequencyCount
            };

            using (WindowedFourierAnalyser windowedFourierAnalyser = new WindowedFourierAnalyser(windowPropagator)) {
                windowedFourierAnalyser.Targets.Add(crossSpectral);
                await Task.Run(() => windowedFourierAnalyser.Analyse(data[xIndex].Standardise().ToArray(), data[yIndex].Standardise().ToArray())).ConfigureAwait(true);
            }

            t = new FixedStepDataSequence() { Count = data[xIndex].Length, Step = samplingInterval, Name = "time", Unit = "s" };
            averagedF = new FixedStepDataSequence() { Count = crossSpectral.CrossSpectrum.Count, Minimum = startFrequencyIndex * frequencyStep, Step = frequencyStep, Name = "frequency", Unit = "Hz" };

            frequencyStep = 1.0 / (data[xIndex].Length * samplingInterval);
            startFrequencyIndex = (int)(startFrequency / frequencyStep);
            frequencyCount = (int)(endFrequency / frequencyStep) - startFrequencyIndex + 1;

            using (FourierTransformer fourierTransformer = new FourierTransformer(data[xIndex].Length, (TetheredSun.Spectral.Window)window.GetType().New())) {
                xSpectrum = new ComplexDataSequence(Spectrum.Amplitude(fourierTransformer.Transform(data[xIndex]), false, startFrequencyIndex, frequencyCount));
                xSpectrum.Name = $"Spectrum of {channels[xIndex].Name}";
                xSpectrum.Unit = $"{channels[xIndex].Unit} rms";
                ySpectrum = new ComplexDataSequence(Spectrum.Amplitude(fourierTransformer.Transform(data[yIndex]), false, startFrequencyIndex, frequencyCount));
                ySpectrum.Name = $"Spectrum of {channels[yIndex].Name}";
                ySpectrum.Unit = $"{channels[yIndex].Unit} rms";
            }

            totalF = new FixedStepDataSequence() { Count = frequencyCount, Minimum = startFrequencyIndex * frequencyStep, Step = frequencyStep, Name = "frequency", Unit = "Hz" };
// xSpectrum is a custom Complex sequence that iterates over an alternating real-imaginary double array, it has a custom iterator that enumerates the magnitude as a double sequence, but it is converted to double[] with Enumerable.ToArray<T>(), so this should not be a problem:
            spectrumMovingStatistics = xSpectrum.Magnitude.ToArray().MovingStatistics(radius, null, true, true); // This is the offending line. Will throw an exception as there will be too few items in the array.
/* I inserted the following lines for debugging:
            double[] debug = new double[] { 11.0 };
            bool amIEvil = debug.ConsistsOfNumbers(); xSpectrum.Magnitude.ToArray().ConsistsOfNumbers();*/

            for (int i = 0; i < spectrumMovingStatistics[0].Length; i++) {
                spectrumMovingStatistics[1][i] += spectrumMovingStatistics[0][i];
            }

            recording = new Recording() { Name = $"Cross spectrum: {channelNames[xIndex]} v {channelNames[yIndex]}" };
            recording.Add(new Signal<double, double>(t, new DataSequence<double>(data[xIndex], channels[xIndex].Name, channels[xIndex].Unit)) { Name = channels[xIndex].Name });
            recording.Add(new Signal<double, double>(t, new DataSequence<double>(data[yIndex], channels[yIndex].Name, channels[yIndex].Unit)) { Name = channels[yIndex].Name });
            recording.Add(new Signal<double, Complex>(totalF, xSpectrum) { Name = "Spectrum 1" });
            recording.Add(new Signal<double, Complex>(totalF, ySpectrum) { Name = "Spectrum 2" });
            recording.Add(new Signal<double, Complex>(averagedF, new DataSequence<Complex>(crossSpectral.CrossSpectrum, $"Cross-spectrum of {channels[xIndex].Name} and {channels[yIndex].Name}", $"{channels[xIndex].Unit} ∙ {channels[yIndex].Unit} rms")) { Name = "Cross-spectrum" });
            recording.Add(new Signal<double, double>(averagedF, new DataSequence<double>(crossSpectral.CrossSpectrum.Phase.Select(phase => phase / Math.PI).MovingStatistics(10).Select(stats => stats[0]).ToArray(), $"Phase lag between {channels[xIndex].Name} and {channels[yIndex].Name}", $"∙ π rad")) { Name = "Phase lag" });
            recording.Add(new Signal<double, double>(averagedF, new DataSequence<double>(crossSpectral.Coherence, $"Coherence between {channels[xIndex].Name}  and  {channels[yIndex].Name}", "relative units")) { Name = "Coherence" });

            ViewObject = (recordingViewModel = new RecordingViewModel() { Recording = recording });

            recordingViewModel[2].Series.Add(new SeriesViewModel(totalF, spectrumMovingStatistics[0]) { Name = "Moving average" });
            recordingViewModel[2].Series.Add(new SeriesViewModel(totalF, spectrumMovingStatistics[1]) { Name = "Upper Bollinger band" });
            recordingViewModel[2].Series.Add(new SeriesViewModel(totalF, spectrumMovingStatistics[2]) { Name = "Local minimum" });
            recordingViewModel[2].Series.Add(new SeriesViewModel(totalF, spectrumMovingStatistics[3]) { Name = "Local maximum" });

            await Task.Run(() => recording.Save(@$"E:\Temp\{channels[xIndex].Name}-{channels[yIndex].Name} - crossSpectrum.mba")).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

The offending extension method is

```
 public static T[][] MovingStatistics<T>(this IReadOnlyList<T> source, int radius, T[][] target, bool calculateStandardDeviation = false, bool calculateExtrema = false, int startIndex = 0, int length = -1) where T : INumberBase<T>
        {
            if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex >= source.Count) startIndex = 0;
            
            int lower = startIndex - radius;
            int upper = startIndex + radius;
            int count;
            int windowSize = 2 * radius + 1;
            int targetIndex = 0;
            int statisticsCount = 1;
            int minimumIndex = -1;
            int maximumIndex = -1;
    // This is where the trouble is. This evaluates to false and thus the target array will only have 2 elements instead of 4.
            bool isOrderedField = typeof(T).IsAssignableTo(typeof(INumber<>));
            IComparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
            T incoming;
            T outgoing;
            T nextSize;
            T increment;
            T incrementPerSize;
            T oldMean;
            T mean = T.Zero;
            T q = T.Zero;
            T size = T.Zero;
            T minimum = T.Zero;
            T maximum = T.Zero;
            ReadOnlySpan<T> sourceSpan = source.ToReadOnlySpan();


            if (length <= 0) length = source.Count;
            if (lower < 0) lower = 0;
            if (upper >= source.Count) upper = source.Count - 1;
// Here is where what went wrong above propagates its wrongness:
            calculateExtrema &= isOrderedField;
            if (calculateStandardDeviation) ++statisticsCount;
            if (calculateExtrema) {
                minimumIndex = statisticsCount;
                maximumIndex = statisticsCount + 1;
                minimum = T.CreateSaturating(Double.PositiveInfinity);
                maximum = T.CreateSaturating(Double.NegativeInfinity);
                statisticsCount += 2;
            }

            count = 1;

            InitialiseTarget(length);
// The same iteration as below but with Span<T> objects and Unsafe.Add(ref reference, int offset) instead of array indexing -- actually worth it for 3× speed.
            if (!sourceSpan.IsEmpty) return MovingStatisticsSpanIterator<T>(sourceSpan, radius, target, calculateStandardDeviation, calculateExtrema, startIndex, length);

            // Initial stage: filling up the first half of the window.
            for (int i = lower; i <= upper; i++) {
                incoming = source[i];
                increment = incoming - mean; // (x_k - A_(k-1))
                size = T.CreateChecked(count++);    // k in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Rapid_calculation_methods
                incrementPerSize = increment / size; // (x_k - A_(k-1)) / k
                mean += incrementPerSize;  // A_k = A_(k-1) + (x_k - A_(k-1)) /
                if (calculateStandardDeviation) {
                    q += increment * (increment - incrementPerSize);        // Q_k = Q_(k-1) + (x_k - A_(k-1)) * (x_k - A_k), => dQ_k := Q_k - Q_(k-1) = (x_k - A_(k-1)) * (x_k - A_k) =
                                                                            // = increment * (x_k - [A_(k-1) + (x_k - A_(k-1)) / k]) = increment * (x_k - A_(k-1) - increment / k) = increment * (increment - incrementPerSize)
                }
                if (calculateExtrema) {
                    if (comparer.Compare(incoming, minimum) < 0) {
                        minimum = incoming;
                    }
                    if (comparer.Compare(incoming, maximum) > 0) {
                        maximum = incoming;
                    }
                }
            }
            target[0][targetIndex] = mean;
            if (calculateStandardDeviation) {
                target[1][targetIndex] = count > 1 ? (q / (size - T.One)).SquareRoot() : T.Zero;
            }
            if (calculateExtrema) {
                target[minimumIndex][targetIndex] = minimum;
                target[maximumIndex][targetIndex] = maximum;
            }

            ++targetIndex;

            if (targetIndex >= length) return target;

            // Next stage: filling up the second half of the window:
            upper++;
            while (upper < source.Count && count <= windowSize) {
                if (targetIndex >= length) return target;
                incoming = source[upper++];
                increment = incoming - mean; // (x_k - A_(k-1))
                size = T.CreateChecked(count++);    // k in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Rapid_calculation_methods
                incrementPerSize = increment / size; // (x_k - A_(k-1)) / k
                mean += incrementPerSize;  // A_k = A_(k-1) + (x_k - A_(k-1)) / k
                target[0][targetIndex] = mean;
                if (calculateStandardDeviation) {
                    q += increment * (increment - incrementPerSize);        // Q_k = Q_(k-1) + (x_k - A_(k-1)) * (x_k - A_k), => dQ_k := Q_k - Q_(k-1) = (x_k - A_(k-1)) * (x_k - A_k) =
                                                                            // = increment * (x_k - [A_(k-1) + (x_k - A_(k-1)) / k]) = increment * (x_k - A_(k-1) - increment / k) = increment * (increment - incrementPerSize)
                    target[1][targetIndex] = (q / (size - T.One)).SquareRoot();
                }
                if (calculateExtrema) {
                    if (comparer.Compare(incoming, minimum) < 0) {
                        minimum = incoming;
                    }
                    if (comparer.Compare(incoming, maximum) > 0) {
                        maximum = incoming;
                    }
                    target[minimumIndex][targetIndex] = minimum;
                    target[maximumIndex][targetIndex] = maximum;
                }
                ++targetIndex;
            }
// Next stage: advance the window and correct with outgoing and incoming elements.
            if (count > windowSize) {
                count = windowSize;
            }
            size = T.CreateChecked(count);

            while (upper < source.Count) {
                if (targetIndex >= length) return target;
                incoming = source[upper++];
                outgoing = source[lower++];
                increment = incoming - outgoing;
                incrementPerSize = increment / size;
                oldMean = mean;
                mean += incrementPerSize;  // A_k = A_(k-1) + (x_k - A_(k-1)) / k
                target[0][targetIndex] = mean;
                if (calculateStandardDeviation) {
                    q += increment * (incoming + outgoing - mean - oldMean);
                    target[1][targetIndex] = (q / (size - T.One)).SquareRoot();
                }
                if (calculateExtrema) {
                    if (outgoing == minimum || outgoing == maximum) {
                        (minimum, maximum) = source.Extrema(lower, count);
                    }
                    if (comparer.Compare(incoming, minimum) < 0) {
                        minimum = incoming;
                    }
                    if (comparer.Compare(incoming, maximum) > 0) {
                        maximum = incoming;
                    }
                    (target[minimumIndex][targetIndex], target[maximumIndex][targetIndex]) = (minimum, maximum);
                }
                ++targetIndex;
            }

            
            // Last stage, wherein there are only outgoing elements:
            while (count > radius) {
                if (targetIndex >= length) return target;
                size = T.CreateChecked(count--);
                nextSize = size - T.One;
                outgoing = source[lower++];
                oldMean = mean;
                mean = mean * (size / nextSize) - outgoing / nextSize;
                target[0][targetIndex] = mean;
                if (calculateStandardDeviation) {
                    q += size * oldMean * oldMean - outgoing * outgoing - nextSize * mean * mean;
                    target[1][targetIndex] = (q / (nextSize - T.One)).SquareRoot();
                }
                if (calculateExtrema) {
                    if (outgoing == minimum || outgoing == maximum) {
                        (minimum, maximum) = source.Extrema(lower, count);
                    }
                    (target[minimumIndex][targetIndex], target[maximumIndex][targetIndex]) = (minimum, maximum);
                }
                ++targetIndex;
            }

            return target;

            // Local functions:
            void InitialiseTarget(int targetSize)
            {
                if (target is null) {
                    target = new T[statisticsCount][];
                    for (int i = 0; i < statisticsCount; i++) {
                        target[i] = new T[targetSize];
                    }
                } else if (target.Length < statisticsCount) {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"An array of row size {target.Length} cannot accommodate moving statistics of {statisticsCount} elements.", nameof(target));
                } else if (target[0].Length < targetSize) {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"An array of column size {target[0].Length} cannot accommodate the moving statistics of a sequence with a count of {targetSize}.", nameof(target));
                }
            }
        }
```

The project file of the calling project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>True</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MahApps.Metro" Version="2.4.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="MahApps.Metro.IconPacks" Version="4.11.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TetheredSun.2.0\TetheredSun.Acq\TetheredSun.Acq.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TetheredSun.2.0\TetheredSun.Charting\TetheredSun.Charting.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TetheredSun.2.0\TetheredSun.MahAppsExtensions\TetheredSun.MahAppsExtensions.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TetheredSun.2.0\TetheredSun.Office\TetheredSun.Office.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TetheredSun.2.0\TetheredSun.Spectral\TetheredSun.Spectral.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TetheredSun.2.0\TetheredSun.Wpf\TetheredSun.Wpf.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TetheredSun.2.0\TetheredSun\TetheredSun.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and that of the project containing the called extension method

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64;x86</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I could not find any `global.json` file in any of the projects concerned.

Comment: It would be very interesting to see the repro. How do you validate the `amIEvil == False`? Is it logging or does it happen during debug? What is actual type of passed variable, how the method is actually called?

Comment: I just placed a breakpoint after the initialisation of `amIEvil` and checked the value with the Visual Studio debugger tool.

I could put the original code here but it would be too long and the line I inserted is completely uncoupled from everything else. The very same literal `double[]` array gives different results in different solutions. I do not even know which one is the expected behaviour: the one that returns `true` or the one that returns `false`.

Comment: Full code would be great (if possible), TBH, including project and repository files (like `global.json`).

Comment: TBH I don't see anything in the code for `amIEvil`. And I was not able to reproduce locally. The only guess I have - different SDK/runtime minor/patch versions are used (and the offending project has `global.json`). It would be really interesting to see the repro on your machine if possible.

Comment: I commented it out because I wanted to show the original code but it is there in the comments. I have decided to go with the `IsAssignableToGenericType(...)` method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74616/how-to-detect-if-type-is-another-generic-type/1075059#1075059). With that, it works perfectly. Still, it is so strange that such a type check can be so fragile that we need to dig into configuration files.

Comment: Also see [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/78619)