# Why does checking if a Type of System.Int32 is assignable to Type of INumber<> return false in a unit test?

Tags: c#, .net, mstest, .net-7.0

This statement when run from a console application sets 'x' to `true`:

```
var x = 3.GetType().IsAssignableTo(typeof(INumber<>)); // x == true
```

The same statement when run inside a unit test sets `x` to `false`.  Why?

[image: var x = 3.GetType().IsAssignableTo(typeof(INumber<>));]

Comment: This appears to be a difference between .NET 7 and .NET 8 (preview) FWIW. On .NET 7 it's true, on .NET 8 it's false

Comment: @canton7 So legit breaking change?  FYI in both cases this is running under .NET 7

Comment: As far as I can tell, the documentation doesn't actually describe what should happen in this case, so I'm not sure this was ever defined behaviour

Comment: Also, false in .NET 5, true in .NET 6. So it was false, then went true in .NET 6 and 7, then back to false.

Comment: @canton7 But `INumber<>` has only existed since .NET 7

Comment: @DavidG Try with any other interface which `int` implements (I used `IComparable<T>`) or indeed any struct/generic interface combination

Comment: @DavidG you can always simulate it with other types/interfaces though.

Comment: Possibly related but without repo/answer - https://stackoverflow.com/q/76761710/2501279

Comment: @canton7 Sure, just making sure we're talking about the same thing here.

Comment: @rory.ap _"So legit breaking change? FYI in both cases this is running under .NET 7"_ - doubtfully, it was never defined in docs.

Comment: Just use `3.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsConstructedGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(INumber<>))`

Comment: This is a bug which was fixed in .NET 8. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

This was a bug that was [introduced in .NET 6](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/78619), and [fixed in .NET 8](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/83858).

The correct behaviour is that [uninstantiated generics are not AssignableTo](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/78619#issuecomment-1329877073).

I guess this makes sense, as you can't write `INumber<> x = 3`.

Comment: _"I guess this makes sense"_ - note that according to docs it should work for generics despite you not being able to write `T x = ...;  INumber<> y= x;`

Comment: @GuruStron Where in the docs? I saw nothing about open generic types

Comment: _"The current type is a generic type parameter, and `targetType` represents one of the constraints of the current type."_ - in the [returns `true` section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignableto?view=net-7.0#returns)

Comment: @GuruStron That's about generic type *parameters*, not open generic types. Specifically, I think this is saying if you have the method `Foo<T> where T : IThing`, and get the Type object for the `T`, then `T` is assignable to `IThing`. [See `IsGenericTypeParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isgenerictypeparameter?view=net-7.0#system-type-isgenerictypeparameter).

Comment: Agree, seems that I misunderstood it a bit.

Comment: My guess was that it could handle open generics too i.e. when `where T : INumber<T>`. Maybe the question I linked confused me=)

Answer (score 2):

The actual question should be "why it returns `true`" and that is targeted by [@canton7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76820384/2501279), but in addition to it I would like to add corresponding quote from the [`Type.IsAssignableTo` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignableto?view=net-7.0#returns):

> #### Returns
>
> `true` if any of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The current instance and targetType represent the same type.
> - The current type is derived either directly or indirectly from targetType. > - The current type is derived directly from targetType if it inherits from targetType;
> - the current type is derived indirectly from targetType if it inherits from a succession of one or more classes that inherit from targetType.
> - targetType is an interface that the current type implements.
> - The current type is a generic type parameter, and targetType represents one of the constraints of the current type.
> - The current type represents a value type, and `targetType` represents `Nullable<c>`.

> `false` if none of these conditions are true, or if `targetType` is null.

Since none of `true` ones match the case the check should always has returned `false`.

Change your code to:

```cs
var isINumber = 3.GetType()
   .GetInterfaces()
   .Any(i => i.IsConstructedGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(INumber<>))
```

Or

```
var isINumberOfInt32 = 3.GetType().IsAssignableTo(typeof(INumber<int>));
```

Answer (score -1):

I will assume that your question can be translated to "how may the result of false be logically explained", rather than to "what was the exact purpose of the developers of the language/framework".

I am not a developer of the language/framework, so I can only make sense of the logic based on what is publicly available.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumber-1?view=net-8.0

We can see that `INumber<TSelf>`

[image]

is basically a "number of TSelf". And `TSelf` can be as follows:

[image]

Now, your `System.Int32` is a signed value stored on 32 bits. It can overflow a `System.Int16`, for example, which is a perfectly valid possibility for `TSelf`, so, potentially you have overflows, which, as a possibility makes a `false` more correct than a `true` for your unit test.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is correct or even relevant. This behaviour can be seen with *any* open generic type -- it has nothing to do with `INumber<T>` specifically. Therefore, any answer which is based solely on `INumber<T>` cannot be correct.

Comment: @canton7 I'm firmly convinced that the possibility of having overflows is relevant.

Comment: How do you explain the change in behaviour of `typeof(int).IsAssignableTo(typeof(IComparable<>))`, then?

Comment: @canton7 what was its result previously and what is its result now?

Comment: Exactly the same as `INumber<T>`. `IsAssignableFrom` returned `false` pre-.NET 5, was erroneously changed to return `true` in .NET 6 and 7, and was fixed to return `false` in .NET 8.

Comment: @canton7 then this is a particular case of a larger pattern. But the possibility of overflow is still relevant and something to watch out for in all versions where it's possible.

Comment: It's not relevant to the question being asked, is my point. I'm not sure it's relevant to overflows either: an `INumber<int>` will never magically turn into an `INumber<short>` (or vice versa) because of an overflow. Overflows in C# wrap (or throw an exception), they don't cause promotion to a larger type

Comment: @canton7 I understand your position, even though I disagree. Thank you for providing the reason for the down-vote.